# How to render a nested component with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is a ***noob*** question. I'm developing a universal react application using *react-isomorphic-starterkit* boilerplate (https://github.com/RickWong/react-isomorphic-starterkit). I would create a "fixed" sidebar on the left that contains links to the other pages rendered on a child of the main container on the right. Here's my code: 
*routes.js*

```
module.exports = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>
            <Route path='/inbox' component={Inbox} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

*Main.js*

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props,context);
        console.log('Main props', props);
        console.log('Main context', props);
    }
    /**
     * componentWillMount() runs on server and client.
     */
    componentWillMount () {
        if (__SERVER__) {
            console.log("Hello server");
        }

        if (__CLIENT__) {
            console.log("Hello client");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs on server and client.
     */
    render () {
        return (
                <App/>
        )
    }
}
```

*App.js*

```
class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    console.log('App props ', props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
          <Sidebar/>
          <RightContent />
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

*RightContent.js*

```
class RightContent extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <div id="b" style={{backgroundColor:"#EEF0F4", width:"100%"}}>
        <NavBar />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Problem is: Inbox component (a simple `<div>`) is not rendering when I click on the sidebar with `<Link to="...">` tag. I don't know if the following thing is correct: as you can see, in `App.js` class constructor prints `props` variable...but the output is `undefined`. However, in `Main.js` props are printed correctly. react-router version is greater than 2. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing props down to `App`, so unless you use the location context, it won't have them.

You should do...

```
render () {
  return (
    <App {...this.props}/>
  )
}
```

Then, you should have access to `this.props.children` in `App` to render the nested route(s). You'll need to specify that in `RightContent` too...

```
render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar/>
      <RightContent>
        {this.props.children}
      </RightContent>
    </div>
  )
}
```

See the tutorial in the docs... https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/Introduction.md#with-react-router